# JavaScript code runs in node.js but not browser

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
async function my_function() {
    console.log("Hello");

    let response = await fetch(url, {
        mode: 'no-cors'
    })
        .then(response => response.json()) // THIS LINE

        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
}
```

which works great if I include `const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));` in node.js. This however, does not run in the browser. When I run this code in google chrome I get this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

relating to the

```
.then(response => response.json()) // THIS LINE
```

line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*Unexpected end of input*" sounds like a JSON parse error to me. Can you verify in the devtools network panel that you're actually getting the response you were expecting?

Comment: @Bergi — The JSON parse error is because the response is opaque because it is set to `no-cors` mode.

Comment: @digitalniweb  CORS is a fantastic technology as it allows you to lower the built-in security features of the browser when you want to share data and leave them up when it would be a risk to the user's data.

Answer (score -1):

For the browser, you have to enable the cors-policy otherwise it will not works. So in your API, you must include:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
```

And also disable the no-cors mode.

Comment: How do I do that, and if I later deploy this app, won't my users also have to do that?

Comment: This isn't sufficient since you also have to disable no-cors mode. `"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true` is pointless because the credentials mode is same-origin (the default).

Comment: Yes i've updated my response, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score -1):

Because You mixing Promises with await? Choice one of.
Read about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: No. The use of `await` is pointless but is has nothing to do with the problem